# Convert String to Array update a value and return a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an string that looks like this separated with ('\n')

```
    car_make:Honda
    car_model:Accord
```

I am trying to build a javascript function that updates the value given and returns the updated string.

```
  function updateCar(car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model){
    var car_array = car_str.split('\n');
    var new_car_array = new Array(); 
    if(new_car_make){
        //update new_car_array i.e new_car_array 
       }

     if(new_car_model){
          //update new_car_array i.e new_car_array 
       }

      return new_car_array.toString();
 };
```

so when someone uses the function

```
   updateCar(car_str, 'Acura', 'Integra');
```

the new output looks like this

```
    car_make:Acura
    car_model:Integra
```

Or if the use they do this:

```
    updateCar(car_str, 'Acura', '');
```

The output looks like this

```
    car_make:Acura
    car_model:Accord
```

I am not sure why I can't get this it seems so simple.  I have done searches but maybe i am not searching the right terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var car_str = "car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord";

function updateCar(car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model) {
  var lines = car_str.split('\n');
  var car = {};
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var parts = line.split(':');
    car[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  });

  if (new_car_make) {
    car.car_make = new_car_make;
  }

  if (new_car_model) {
    car.car_model = new_car_model;
  }

  return 'car_make:' + car.car_make + '\ncar_model:' + car.car_model;
};

updateCar(car_str, 'Acura', 'Integra'); // => car_make:Acura\ncar_model:Integra
```

Comment: looks good for the first case but the second case if i pass updateCar(car_str, "Acura" ,"") it comes back with car_make:Acura
car_model:undefined

Comment: Not for me. I get: "car_make:Acura\ncar_model:Accord".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful, but it seems like you'd be better off just adding commas to the end of each line and converting to/from JSON

Edit: You would also have to wrap the values (and maybe the keys) in quotes

Comment: You would also need to surround with `{` and `}` and quote all strings correctly, including the keys.

Comment: Well not the keys on most modern browsers, right? But yeah, not as simple as I said. Still, why invent a new encoding when you already have json

Comment: To convert a string to a valid JSON object, you have 2 options: `JSON.parse(str)`, which requires fully valid JSON, which _includes double quoted keys_; or `eval()` which is generally a _pretty bad idea_ and will not make you popular, though it will allow you to not have to quote the keys.

Comment: ah good point. I'm used to working with JSON conversion functions from external JS libraries

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to create a new array to store the result of your processing. You can just use the array you make from calling split

```
  function updateCar(car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model){
    var car_array = car_str.split('\n'); 
    if(new_car_make){
       }

     if(new_car_model){
       }

      return car_array.toString();
 };
```

Since you have a consistent string beign passed in we know what the contents of `car_array` will be. For example if you pass in

```
car_make:Honda
car_model:Accord
```

Your array will look like this

```
["car_make:Honda","car_model:Accord"]
```

when we successfully enter one of the if statements we know we have a new value to set in our array. Since we know the structure and contents of our array we can set the new values by index.

```
  function updateCar(car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model){
    var car_array = car_str.split('\n'); 
    if(new_car_make){
        car_array[0] = "car_make:" + new_car_make; 
       }

     if(new_car_model){
          car_array[1] = "car_model:" + new_car_model; 
       }

      return car_array.toString();
 };
```

So if we call `updateCar('car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord', 'Acura', 'Integra');`  during execution our function will look like this:

```
  function updateCar('car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord', 'Acura', 'Integra'){
    var car_array = 'car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord'.split('\n'); 
    if('Acura'){
        ["car_make:Honda","car_model:Accord"][0] = "car_make:" + 'Acura'; 
       }

     if('Integra'){
          ["car_make:Acura","car_model:Accord"][1] = "car_model:" + 'Integra'; 
       }

      return ["car_make:Acura","car_model:Integra"].toString();
```

which will return `"car_make:Acura,car_model:Integra"`. We can use [Array.join(separator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to change how we join the elements in our array. Since we passed in a `\n` delimited string we can use `\n` to join the string to get something out that looks like what we put in.

```
 function updateCar(car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model){
    var car_array = car_str.split('\n'); 
    if(new_car_make){
        car_array[0] = "car_make:" + new_car_make; 
       }

     if(new_car_model){
          car_array[1] = "car_model:" + new_car_model; 
       }

      return car_array.join("\n");
 };
```

So now if we call `updateCar('car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord', 'Acura', 'Integra');` we will get

```
car_make:Acura
car_model:Integra
```

And if we pass in a blank string for either parameter we will not enter that particular if statement so the value will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, however, are you sure the line deliminator is really "\n" and not a CR or LF?  *String.fromCharCode(13) or String.fromCharCode(10)*

```
var str="car_make:Honda\ncar_model:Accord";
var delim1 = "\n"; 
var delim2 = ":";
var formatAttrs= function (attrs) {
    return "car_make"+delim2+attrs.car_make+
        delim1+"car_model"+delim2+attrs.car_model;
};
var parseStr = function (car_str){
    var attrs= {};
    car_str.split(delim1).forEach(function(row){
        var segments = row.split(delim2);
        attrs[segments[0]]=segments[1];
    });
    return attrs;
};
var updateCar = function (car_str, new_car_make, new_car_model){
    var attrs = parseStr(car_str);
    attrs.car_make = new_car_make || attrs.car_make;
    attrs.car_model= new_car_model|| attrs.car_model;
    return formatAttrs(attrs);
};

console.log(updateCar(str, 'Buick', 'Regal'));
console.log(updateCar(str, '', 'Regal'));
console.log(updateCar(str, 'Buick', null));
```

Returns:

```
car_make:Buick
car_model:Regal

car_make:Honda
car_model:Regal

car_make:Buick
car_model:Accord
```